# Django modelform formset first form required

Tags: django, forms, formset

I have a Django form which is a modelForm:

```
class EducationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Education
```

But it is actually used as a formset:

```
queryset_education = Education.objects.filter(member = edit_member)
EducationFormSet = modelformset_factory(Education, form = EducationForm)
form_education  = EducationFormSet(queryset = queryset_education)
```

How can I force the first form to be required?
I saw some similar questions in StackOverflow... none helped me, as I don't have a class that inherit from BaseFormSet (Should I create one?)

Thanks!

Tidhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should define a formset class with a `clean` method, and pass that in as the `formset` argument to `modelformset_factory`.